# How can I read environment variables inside the git_repository function?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to download a non-public git repository using [git_repository](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/repo/git#git_repository), so I would like to use something like

```py
def load_my-repo_repo():
    git_repository(
        name = "my-repo",
        remote = "https://user:${PASSWORD}@git-server.com/my-repo.git",
    )
```

I have tried with `bazel test --test_env=PASSWORD=${TOKEN}`, and with `ctx.os.environ` but I have not been able to use the environment variable that contains the password.

How can I read an environment variable inside the git_repository function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to approach this this way.
`.netrc` files are the way to pass authentication credentials for private git repos.

Create a file with the following format in your home directory with permissions 0600:

```
machine git-server.com
login user
password SECRET
```